# this property scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code,

```
var a= document.getElementById("demo");
a.onclick = function(){
   alert(this.innerHTML)
   setTimeout(function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML)
  },1000);
}
```

I got correct innerHTML value from first alert statement. But i got undefined value in second alert statement. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Because `this` in JavaScript is dynamic. You can do `var that = this` or do `setTimeout(function(){ alert(this.innerHTML); }.bind(this),1000)`.

Comment: you miss out semicolons after both alert calls, and after the last curly bracket

Comment: @JonDinham JavaScript sports automatic semicolon insertion. In all these cases semicolons are optional (although I'd use them too).

Answer (score 3):

Because within the function there you have function which is nested and in nested function the `this` keyword will refer to the window.

So, You can use like this:

```
var a= document.getElementById("demo");
a.onclick = function(){
   var that = this;
   alert(this.innerHTML)
   setTimeout(function(){
        alert(that.innerHTML)
  },1000);
}
```

Alternatively, you may use bind method:

```
var a= document.getElementById("demo");
a.onclick = function(){
  //var that = this;
   alert(this.innerHTML)
   setTimeout(function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML)
  }.bind(this),1000); // now this refers to the clicked element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not correct, the `this` in the `setTimeout` is scoped to the `window` object. you have to save the last scope and use it. like `var that = that` before the setTimeout:

```
var a= document.getElementById("demo");
a.onclick = function(){
   // save scope
   var that = this;

   alert(this.innerHTML)
   setTimeout(function(){
        // since this is a new function, the "this" refers to the window object.
        alert(that.innerHTML) // changed "this" to "that"
  },1000);
}
```