# How to find the right "this" object in inner classes?

Tags: javascript, this, inner-classes

I am writing a piece of JavaScript like that:

```
MyClassA.prototype.method1 = function(){
    //here, "this" refers to my instance of MyClassA
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://foo.com/foo",
        success: function(data) {
            //OMG! "this" now refers to another object
        }
    }
});
```

I need to access to the `this` element of `MyClassA` in the `success` function. In Java, it is possible to use `MyClassA.this` to refer to the right `this` instance inside an inner class. Is there a comparable way to do that in JavaScript?

Is

```
MyClassA.prototype.method1 = function(){
    var myClassAThis=this;
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://foo.com/foo",
        success: function(data) {
            myClassAThis.method2();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

the standard way to proceed in such situation?

Comment: You have answered yourself, that's correct way to do and another way is to do with bind. you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137044/this-property-scope-in-javascript/25137098#25137098...

Comment: I don't see any inner classes in your code? `MyClassA` is the only constructor that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicate !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common pattern is to set `this` into a variable, yes. However, what you're describing creates an implicit **global variable**. To prevent it, use the `var` keyword:

```
var that = this;
```

And later

```
that.method2();
```

Another solution would be with a closure.

```
MyClassA.prototype.method1 = function(){
    (function(that) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://foo.com/foo",
            success: function(data) {
                that.method2();
                ...
            }
        });
    })(this);
});
```

Comment: well spotted: I had forgotten the "var".

Comment: That closure looks very unnecessary. It also is way longer…

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not keen on closures - it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: @Bergi "Way longer" exactly one extra line from setting a variable.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: One line more than declaring a variable, and notably adding one level of unnecessary indentation.

Comment: @Bergi personally speaking, I'd use a module pattern here instead of prototyping. It make things a lot cleaner. But sure, whichever works. I like this style better than `that = this`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do

```
MyClassA.prototype.method1 = function(){   
  return $.ajax({
    url : "http://foo.com/foo"      
  }
});

MyClassA.prototype.method2 = function(){   
   this.method1().done(function(data) {
    //do method2 code
  })

});
```

Comment: Please add some clarification to make it a good answer.

Comment: This doesn't apply as `method2()` shouldn't implicitly invoke `method1()`, but the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClassA.prototype.method1 = function(){
myClassAThis=this; //1
$.ajax({
    url : "http://foo.com/foo",
    success: function(data) {
        myClassAThis.method2(); //2
        ...
    }
}
});
```

which object "this" refers to at any any point in your code actually depends on how you invoke the function.

In this case, 
1. Either as a usual function. Exampe:- functionName()
2. Or as a method invocation. Example:- new someOuterFunction().someInnerFunction()

(note : there are two other types of invocations)

In the first case, the this parameter which is implicitly passed into the function scope is the global object context, which in the case of the browser is the window object.

In the second case, the this parameter actually refers to the instance on which the function was invoked, in this case it would be the someOuterFunction instance.

Keeping those two in mind, 
if you look at the above code //1, what "this" refers to depends on how exactly you invoke the method1. If you happen to invoke it as a normal function, then this refers to the global object, and thus it will look for  method2 in the global context and not MyClassA function.

In you happen to invoke method1 as method invocation by referring to an instance of MyClassA then, "this" actually points to that instance. Which would then search for Method2 in the MyClassA instance(or function) and invoke that.

Hope that helps!! or at least clear up the confusion.. :)

Comment: I was not confused before reading your answer... now I am a bit. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your `myClassAThis` is an implicit global.